# Are the \[ and \begin{equation} used interchangeably?

Tags: equations, amsmath

When I use double dollar signs `$$` or `\[` and `\]` to begin and end math mode I have no problem compiling the file. When I substitute them with `\begin{equation}` and `\end{equation}` correspondingly I get an error.

For example:

```
\[
\label{eq:stress_strain_eq}
\left\{\begin{array}{c}
\sigma_x \\
\sigma_y \\
\tau_{xy}
\end{array}\right\}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
\overline{Q}_{11}   & \overline{Q}_{12}  & \overline{Q}_{16}    \\[0.3em]
\overline{Q}_{12}   & \overline{Q}_{22}  & \overline{Q}_{26}    \\[0.3em]
\overline{Q}_{16}   & \overline{Q}_{26}  & \overline{Q}_{66}
\end{bmatrix}
\cdot
\left\{\begin{array}{c}
\epsilon_x \\
\epsilon_y \\
\gamma_{xy}
\end{array}\right\}
\]
```

produces the right result but I cannot reference it. I thought that the three options were interchangeable.

Comment: What error exactly?

Comment: They should be *interchangeable*, yes. So, if you use `\begin{equation}`, don't include `\[` or `$$`. Also see [Why is `\[` … `\]` preferable to `$$`?](http://goo.gl/GvmWy)

Comment: I read somewhere that $$ was the old syntax which has now been superseded by `\[`. The problem is now solved by moving the `\label{}` at the end of the block just before `\end{equation}`

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 10):

The environments

```
\begin{equation}
 ...
\end{equation}
```

and

```
\[ ... \]
```

are not interchangeable, as the first will produce an equation number, while the latter will not. A `\label{...}` command in the latter will not produce an error, but it has no effect since there is no counter it may refer to.

The equivalent to the latter would be the starred version of the `equation` environment, which is provided by the `amsmath` package:

```
\begin{equation*}
 ...
\end{equation*}
```